# Designing a Cloud BigTable: Millions of Rows X Millions of Columns?

Tags: bigtable

I'm wondering if the following table design for BigTable is legit. From what I read, having millions of sparse columns should work, but would it work well?

The idea is to keep time-based "samples" in columns (each is a few Kb). I expect to have millions of rows, where each would have a limited number of entries (~10-50) as values in the table. Each column in the table represents a timespan of (say, ) 10 seconds. and since there are roughly 2.6 seconds in a month, a year would take about 3M columns. I intend to use row-scans to fetch rows by prefix - usually just a handful of rows per fetch.

so, to sum:

- the table will contain (million rows X 50 samples per row, each a few kb): 50M items
- but the table's dimensions are (million rows X million columns): a trillion cells.

Now, I know that empty cells don't take space and the whole "table" metaphor isn't really apt to BT, but I'm still wondering: does the above represent a valid use-case for BigTable?

Answer (score 1):

Based on the [Google docs](https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/overview), Cloud Bigtable is a sparsely populated table that can scale to billions of rows and **thousands of columns**. About the limitation of Cloud Bigtable rows and columns, Cloud Bigtable [Rows can be big but are not infinite](https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/schema-design-time-series#rows-not-infinite), the rows can contain ~100 column families and millions of columns but the recommendation is 100MB for row size then 10MB for column value.

Therefore, In BigTable, the limit of the data within table is based on data size instead of the number of columns or rows (except for "Column families per table"). I believe your use-case is valid and could have a million of rows and columns as long as the values is within the [hard limit](https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/quotas#limits-data-size). As a best practice, [design your schema](https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/schema-design) to keep the size of your data.

Comment: thank you for this! looks like we've been reading similar articles :]
Though according to this (https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/schema-design-time-series), "Rows in Cloud Bigtable can contain ~100 column families and millions of columns, with a 100 MB limit on each value stored in a column." so now I dunno if its thousands or millions...

Comment: I believe there's a limit on the number of column families, but not on the number of columns inside each.

Comment: Yes, there's a limit on the number of column families and the limit of columns inside will be based on the data size not on the number. So to achieve your goal that having a million of columns use properly the data size and doing the best practices of [designing schema](https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/schema-design) will help for you.